# Update pivot table with updateExistingPivot - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I have 2 models (surveys and categories) in a many-to-many relationship through a pivot table.

I want to be able to update these records with updateExistingPivot but I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `category_survey` set `0` = 2, `1` = 3 where `survey_id` = 2 and `category_id` in (2))
```

model survey:

```
 public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)
            ->as('categories');
    }
```

I'm trying to call the method like this:

```
$survey->categories()->updateExistingPivot($survey->id, $request['categorias']);
```

$request['categorias'] contains an array of category ids.

Can you help me? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the [sync](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations)() method is more suitable for your case, this method construct many-to-many associations and accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table:

```
$survey->categories()->sync($request['categorias']);
```

Comment: Thanks @OMR Your proposal has helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you need to pass `$category->id` instead of `$survey->id`.
2. Check your `$request['categorias']` it need to be key/value array e.g. `['name' => 'foo']`

Here is the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-a-record-on-the-intermediate-table).